# Excel macro add two cells into one of them

Tags: vba, excel

I am absolutely new in macro and need a little help.

The two columns are "O" and "P". After a user writes a number into O2 and clicks double (or press a button) the macro has to add O2 and P2 together and show the result in P2. The problem is it should work for O3-P3, O4-P-4 until forever but O1-P1.

Can anybody help?
It would be great if the value was deleted in O2 after the double click (or button).

Comment: I think you should re-consider your design. Why don't you use a helper column lets say Q to calculate O+P and then group and hide O and P? Using formulas for this task would be Excel's strength, this is what it is designed for. Also make sure you include the code in your question  showing what you already have tried, because this is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, usually you have to do some code and then you ask for input on what is not working/what you want to achieve. It is not cool to come and ask for free code.

That being said, the work here is kinda slow right now, and this wasn't that hard.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row, 16))) Is Nothing Then
         Selection.Value = Selection.Value + Cells(Selection.Row, 15).Value
         Cells(Selection.Row, 15).Value = vbNullString
    End If
End Sub
```

You have to put this code on the sheet you want the Double Click to happen. If you don't know how, you do it by pressing `ALT+F11`. Then, on the left, you click on the sheet (In my case `Plan1`. It may vary based on the language your excel is. Here is a reference image
[image: Reference image]

So, after you did this, you paste the code on the right and it will work. But how does it work?

The first line, `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)` defines when the code will be executed. As you asked, it is on double click. If you want to change the trigger (Like in a button, for example), it's here you need to change.

The second line checks for the valid range of action. It checks if the `Range`is between `Cells(2,16)`
, which means `Cell at Row 2 and Column 16` AKA `P2`and `Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row, 16)`. This second part is weird because you mentioned "Go forever". So, instead of saying a specific row, like I did with row 2 on the first part, it now checks which is the last row of columns 16. The specific to get the last row is `Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row`, basically meaning this part of the range is `Cell at last row and Column 16`, AKA `P..something`

Since now we have our range of action, we need to make what you want, right? Adding them together. Which is line 3. `Selection.Value` returns the value of the cell you selected with the first click. Remember this will only work if it is within the range defined at line 2.
Since you have the value, you say that `Selection.Value = Selection.Value + Cells(Selection.Row, 15).Value`, so it sets the value to itself + the cell at the same row (`Selection.Row`) at column 15 (`Column "O"`).
After that, it sets the value of the `Column "O"`to empty with `vbNullString`. If you want, you could replace it with 0, so this would also work.

And that's it. I just kindly ask for some research and some tries before asking for code. It is ok to get stuck. It is ok to not know how to do things. Don't feel afraid to ask for help. Just show some code next time.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Although I had a really basic code (I added the values of 2 cells but not two columns) I did not know I should show some code, next time I will definitely do it.

Comment: If you have a bit more time.On the sheet I want to use the code already has another code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("O:O"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 18).Value = Date
    End If
End Sub          

When I use your code or this individually they work but when I try to mix them something goes wrong. I tried to paste both of them as two different codes, I tried to use elseif, next and most of the things I found on the internet but none of them worked. I guess it is is pretty easy and I m just too noob for this.

Comment: Add the code after the `End Sub`. Each code starts at a `Sub` and finish after the `End Sub`

Comment: I have tried that but when I tried to actually use it the excel says ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change

Comment: Are you sure you didn't double the worksheet_change code? I mean, the code I provide has nothing to do with `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: Yeah it works with your code but when I use the code bellow It does not. Thanks for you help anyway it is not your code so I open another question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution listed below applies simplified logic: as User enter the value in any cell in column O, this code will update column P (e.g. P3.Value =O3.Value + P3.Value) and then clear the content of the cell in column O (O3 in this example)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 15 Then
        Range("P" & Target.Row).Value = Target.Value + Range("P" & Target.Row).Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case you do not need any button or double_click event handler. Hope this may help

Comment: Thank you, it is great and works as the other one before you. Thank you!

Comment: If you have a bit more time.On the sheet I want to use the code already has another code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("O:O"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 18).Value = Date
    End If
End Sub          

When I use your code or this individually they work but when I try to mix them something goes wrong. I tried to paste both of them as two different codes, I tried to use elseif, next and most of the things I found on the internet but none of them worked. I guess it is is pretty easy and I m just too noob for this.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. If you have more questions please post them separately. Best regards,